# NAudio - Mp3FileReader - медленный вывод аудио

Tags: c#, naudio, lame

Я преобразую входящий поток wav в mp3 через Lame этой функцией:

```
public static MemoryStream WavToMP3(byte[] wavFile)
    {
        using(var retMs = new MemoryStream())
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(wavFile))
        using(var rdr = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(22050, 1)))
        using(var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(retMs, rdr.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.ABR_128))
        {
            rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
            wtr.Flush();
            return new MemoryStream(retMs.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Из другого источника приходит сигнал (записанный на WaveIn или полученный подобным образом).
Этот звуковой сигнал в виде массива байт окунается в функцию.

```
static Mp3FileReader r;

    public static void Broadcast(byte[] data)
    {
        r = new Mp3FileReader(WavToMP3(data));
        Console.Title = r.XingHeader.Frames.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Frames Count = " + r.XingHeader.Frames.ToString());

        int framePos = 0;

        while ((frame = r.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
        {
            framePos++;

            Console.WriteLine("[ SR={0} BIT={1} Lenght={2}  ] ", frame.SampleRate, frame.BitRate, frame.FrameLength );

            foreach(Consumer c in WebCast.Clients) c.Send(frame.RawData);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
    }
```

Данный код переводит байты wav в mp3. Все бы ничего, но **каждые эти 6 кадров** на выходе через **HTTP** у клиента звук как-будто замедленный прерывистый. Ранее этим же *Mp3FileReader*-ом я сохранял данные на диск, там каких-либо искажений (проигран через WMP ui) замечено не было.
Вестимо, искажение в байтах числится в *frame.RawData*.
Я не зря оставил команды вывода в консоль данных кадров, вот такая у нас раскадровка по блокам(по 6), каждая строка - один кадр: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/r7ZvQ1hu)

Перерыв весь интернет, нашел только это, но, говоря честно, я не понял до конца где и что надо убрать в моем коде, дабы искажения не было: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444669/slow-reading-of-mp3-files-with-naudio

И тут у человека что-то подобное было, но это не то: https://coderpapers.com/question/2203124/

Буду благодарен за любую помощь или направление. Спасибо!

---

В двух словах: кадры с mp3 воспроизводятся через браузер MPEG-ом искаженно(замедленно, прерывисто, с отставанием). Согласно изученным результатам, полагаю, что кроме чистых данных, в кадрах есть еще какой-то мусор, который и дает эти искажения в плеере.

Comment: код Mp3FileReader-a https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/e359ca0566e9f9b14fee1ba6e0ec17e4482c7844/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/Mp3FileReader.cs

Comment: Как вы это дело в интернет передаёте? Через byte-массив, или через stream? Попробуйте разбить программу на куски и набрать статистику по времени работы каждого куска - тогда найдёте где затык... И постарайтесь сделать статические буферы, пусть `[ThreadStatic] static byte[] buff` такие, но поменьше юзать GC и всякие ф-ции с# - оптимизировать преобразования на с#, я думаю сам с# и тормозит вам всё.

Comment: Попытайтесь заменить `new byte[]` - пулами. Возможно... как вариант - перепишите либу декомпрессор на `с++` или на `с++/cli` (при условии что будете использовать пулы, malloc/free - использование к минимуму, при чём free - лучше не делать вообще), а на с# - чисто интерфейсная часть - взять/положить. (я так понимаю с# нужен что б к IIS прикрутить).

Comment: вот здесь я опубликовал больше кода: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread2411263.html

Comment: по скорости вряд ли дело. я воспроизводил на колонки и в wav, и записывал в mp3 файл, но по скорости все ок. да и 4 кб не такие уж и большие суммы, как мне кажется, чтобы ему стонать. за совет спасибо. там кроме тормозов еще слышны какие-то шумы (извините за грубость - на бздешь похоже)

Comment: Читайте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056188/audio-conversion-lame-c-wav-mp3  - похоже тут почти ваша проблема только на с++.

Comment: про ссылку: благодарю, ознакомился, но нет, все верно, качество не падает, потому что в сохраненном mp3 файле все ок, как и должно звучать
второе: на входе у нас непрерывный поток, который извлекается с любого записывающего цифрового устройства (микрофон, аналоговый вход, ретрансляция потока для динамиков и т.д. и т.п.). Вы правы в том, что я тоже подозреваю, что где-то среди кадров уже MP3 имеется его заголовок согласно документации MP3 из вики и смежных источников. Только вот тогда я не знаю как мне их отфильтровать и по какому признаку.

Comment: вот тут я сделал замеры: https://pastebin.com/r7ZvQ1hu

Comment: они показывают, что все кадры вообще разной длины и даже частотой дискретизации, а так же кол-вом бит. Я вообще не понимаю как так происходит, но звук-то есть, просто искривленный. Я пробовал оставлять кадры только по 128 бит, но получаю что-то типа писков в колонках из firefox-a

Comment: Разный битрейт - это норма для `LAMEPreset.ABR_128`. ABR = **Average BitRate**, он не обязан быть постоянным. По поводу остального - раз при записи в файл все нормально, очевидно, проблема не с преобразованием в MP3, в с передачей по сети. Судя по всему, вы в заголовке указываете постоянный битрейт, а передаете переменный. Так как протокол icecast не документирован, сказать, как это сделать правильно, довольно трудно.